# Equivalent class for /Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Layer.php in Magento2

Tags: magento2, class

What is the equivalent class for
`/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Layer.php` in magento2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Magento 2, you can find the class at

```
\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Model\Layer.php
```

Comment: I have created a seperate question.. I have overridden Layer, but my custom filters are not getting filtered http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/138618/custom-filters-not-applying-for-the-product-collection-after-overriding-magento